# A curious product formula

Tags: elementary-number-theory, products, infinite-product

Fiddling with Mathematica seems to suggest the following:

$$\frac{(2^2)(4^2)(6^2)\cdots(2N^2)}{(1^2)(3^2)(5^2)\cdots(2N-1)^2}=N\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{32N}-\frac{\pi}{128N^2}+o(1/N^2).$$

Does anyone have an explanation or reference for this, or know how the series continues? The next term appears to be around $-\frac{\pi}{411.5N^3}\approx-0.00763$.

Comment: How did you got such an approximation?

Comment: I was looking up the Taylor coefficients for arcsin(x) and started playing with them. I squared everything because the series on the left looks nicer that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first term is $r^2$, where $$r=\frac{2\cdot 4\cdots (2n)}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)}=\frac{(2\cdot 4\cdots (2n))^2}{(2n)!}=\frac{4^nn!n!}{(2n)!}=\frac{4^n}{{2n\choose n}}$$

Now, ${2n \choose n}$ is the [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient), which is known to be approximately $\large \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ for large $n$.

Hence $r^2\approx \pi n$.  You are teasing out more terms of the approximation (then squaring).  You can get as many terms as you like by using terms of the [Stirling series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_formula#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates) to approximate the  factorials.

Comment: PS. This is a pretty neat thing to discover on your own, so kudos Rob.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the famous [Wallis product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product), discovered by [John Wallis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wallis) three or four centuries ago, and it can be seen as a special case of [Euler's infinite product for the sine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem). $$\frac{\sin\pi x}{\pi x}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$$ Take $x=\frac12$ , and Wallis' identity follows.